# High density text field without a label, with a 40dp height

Tags: android, android-layout, material-design

Try to get [field 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Pavi.jpg) like in [docs](https://material.io/design/components/text-fields.html#filled-text-field).

I've already removed floated label using a `app:hintEnabled="false"`. 
But then the [field moves out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Idjv0.jpg) marked with a red arrow.

How to fix it? How to change height of field to 40dp?

Here's xml:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            app:hintEnabled="false"

            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.FilledBox">

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText

                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!--From MDC library-->
<style name="Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputEditText.FilledBox" 
        parent="Base.Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputEditText"> 

    <item name="android:paddingTop">28dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingBottom">12dp</item>
</style>    
<!-- -->

<style name="TextInputEditTextFilledBoxWithoutLabel" 
        parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputEditText.FilledBox">

    <item name="android:paddingTop">12dp</item>
</style>

<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    ...
    style="@style/TextInputEditTextFilledBoxWithoutLabel"
    />
```